# Prepaid SIM card for data usage in Ukraine

Tags: cellphones, data-plans

I'm heading to Ukraine soon as I have in the past, and one problem I've always had is not being able to get access to a data network while I'm there. I know that data and SIM cards exist there, but I'm not sure how to purchase them, as I don't exactly speak Ukrainian or another common language spoken there.

Is there a way that I can purchase, say 500MB or 1GB of prepaid data in the form of a SIM card while I'm still stateside?

I know that my cellular carrier here features a global network, which means that I could theoretically prepay to use my phone there, however a prepaid card is greatly desired in that when it runs out of data, it *stops working*, rather than me coming home to a $2,000 international data bill from my carrier.

Comment: It's usually not too hard to get a local sim card once you're there. I was able to buy a 3G prepay data plan in China, despite not speaking any (useful) Mandarin and the guy in the shop speaking no English. The card was printed in English as well as Chinese. It's much easier to get a sim card in the destination country rather than trying to order it before leaving.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it's easiest just to pick one up there - you'll have a bigger choice.

From [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ukraine#Stay_safe):

> it is advisable to get a local SIM card for your mobile for
>   emergencies and for cheaper local calls/texts. These are widely
>   available, cheap (often free) and easy to 'top-up',

So that side of things is taken care of.

In terms of what you get with a prepaid SIM, or which company to go with, it's a little sparse but [PrepaidWiki's page on Ukraine](http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Ukraine) lists a few of the companies, the prepaid rates and has links to the various websites, so that you can plan before you go.

If you *really* want to get one before you go, there are [companies that will sell you packages for the Ukraine](http://www.cellularabroad.com/packages-ukraine.html?bid=6&aid=CD31&opt=).

Comment: Personally I recommend to use `MTS` operator.